# XmlNodeList doesn't have any SelectSingleNode method in Universal Windows App or XAML

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to get attributes from a XML file:

```
<yweather:location city="London" region="" country="United Kingdom"/>
<yweather:units temperature="C" distance="km" pressure="mb" speed="km/h"/>
<yweather:wind chill="13" direction="280" speed="19.31"/>
<yweather:atmosphere humidity="77" visibility="9.99" pressure="982.05" rising="0"/>
<yweather:astronomy sunrise="6:44 am" sunset="6:58 pm"/>
```

In my Winforms app, I could easily do that by doing (let's say I'm retrieving the value of `city`):

```
string query = String.Format("url");

XmlDocument wData = new XmlDocument();
wData.Load(query);

XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(wData.NameTable);
man.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");

XmlNode channel = wData.SelectSingleNode("rss").SelectSingleNode("channel");

string city = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:location", man).Attributes["city"].Value;
```

But when I try to do that for Universal Windows App(XAML) there is no method called `SelectSingleNode`, at least according to intellisense. How do I go about and do that? Also as it appears not all the classes from C# / .NET framework is accessible in UWP/XAML, so what's going on?

This is what I tried:

```
private async void SomeThing()
{
    string url = String.Format("url");

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync(); 
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    XmlDocument wData = new XmlDocument();
    wData.Load(reader);

    XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(wData.NameTable);
    man.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");

    string city = wData.SelectSingleNode("city").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `XDocument`.

First, get the XML:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=USCA1116");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

Then create the XDocument object from that XML response:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(response);
```

Declare the namespace object:

```
XNamespace yWeather = "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0";
```

Find the first descendant called *namespace+location*:

```
var locationNode = xdoc.Descendants(yWeather + "location").FirstOrDefault();
```

And then get the value of the attribute *city*:

```
var city = locationNode.Attribute("city").Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank You... worked... so whats going on with UWP then? why not all the classes and their methods are supported?